# How to check is it a Retina Display in Python or Terminal?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, command-line-interface, retina-display

I use the Python module [pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/).
It has problems with Retina display's and i must check if the script runs on a computer with a retina display.

I found this code, but it's not working (anymore).

```py
if subprocess.call("system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep 'retina'", shell=True) == 0:
        IS_RETINA = True
```

Is there any other command to check if the computer has a retina display?
I use OSX Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 2):

I just tried, got False. Then when I checked the whole output, I can see string Retina with a capital R. So I changed

```
if subprocess.call("system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep 'retina'", shell=True) == 0:
        IS_RETINA = True
```

to

```
if subprocess.call("system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep -i 'retina'", shell=True) == 0:
        IS_RETINA = True
```

and it worked.

Try that